# Помогите доработать калькулятор стоимости

Tags: jquery, javascript

Здравствуйте. Коротко набросала то, что уже есть - http://jsfiddle.net/ce424/2/

Калькулятор рассчитывает стоимость номера по позициям и выводит общую сумму снизу в "**Итого**", а также кол-во выбранных человек перемножением человек в номере на кол-во номеров, плюс выбранных человек на доп. место плюс детей до 14 лет.

Хотелось бы немного доработать калькулятор. Как сделать так, чтобы при выборе, н-р, `2 номера` в селектах ниже добавлялось поле:

```
            <option value="2">2</option>
```

если 3 номера, то

```
            <option value="2">2</option>
            <option value="3">3</option>
```

Привожу скрипт калькулятора:

```
//Расчет стоимости номера
function initRoom () {
    var totalSum = 0;
    var countData = 0;
    $("input[id^='pos'], select[id^='pos']").each(function() {
        var idElement  = "#"+$(this).attr("id"), //Получаем id элемента
            priceField = parseInt($(idElement+"_price").text()), //Стоимость позиции
            chelField  = parseInt($(idElement+"_chel").text()), //Узнаем количество человек
            countField = parseInt($(this).val()); //значение элемента

        var outdata = priceField * countField;
        if (isNaN(outdata)) outdata = 0; //проверка на невозможность умножения
      if (outdata == 0) {outdata2 = '-';} else {outdata2 = outdata;};
        $(idElement+"_count").text(outdata2); //Выводим сумму по позиции
      totalSum += outdata; countData += chelField*countField;
    });
    $("#total-amount span").text(totalSum);
    $('#AllPrice2').val(totalSum);
    $("#total-persons").text(countData);
}

$(document).ready(function () {
    initRoom ();
});

$("#CountPriceInRoom").change(function() {
    initRoom ();
});
```

Comment: Ну и зачем тут тэг PHP?

Comment: В принципе, незачем. Просто данные динамические и берутся из базы. А я упростила до HTML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Примерно так: http://jsfiddle.net/q9pzk/

Слушайте я перечитал ещё раз ТЗ и понял его по другому, возможно вам подойдёт этот вариант: http://jsfiddle.net/2xdvH/

Comment: Спасибо, @Олег Б, но немного не так. Есть селект, состоящий из списка `номер 1`, `номер 2`, `номер 3`. И есть два селекта доп. места и дети до 14 лет `<select id="pos_2"><option value="0">0</option><option value="1">1</option></select>`. При загрузке страницы видны только эти позиции. В первом селекте при изменении на `номер 2` в тех других селектах должно подгрузиться `<option value="2">2</option>`, а если выбрать `номер 3`, то подгрузится <option value="2">2</option><option value="3">3</option>. В общем динамически option должен увеличиваться на ту цифру, которую выбрали в Номере.

Comment: а вы переделали мой фиддл, заранее вставили `<option value="2">2</option><option value="3">3</option>` :)

Comment: Этот гляньте: http://jsfiddle.net/2xdvH/

Comment: Вот это другое дело! Спасибо! Какие же тут люди молодцы!

Comment: Спасибо вам за интересные вопросы. Удачной разработки!

Comment: Ну ладно, а можно еще немного доработать, не полным переписыванием #pos_2 и #pos_3 а как-нибудь append'ом, а то уже выбранные позиции обнуляются. Если я выбираю 3 номера и доп.мест - 3, а потом передумываю и выбираю 2 номера, нужно чтобы 3-й option исчез, а selected теперь должен стоять на последнем в списке, т.е. на 2-м. А если я снова выберу 2 номера, то selected должен остаться на 2-м.

Comment: Я конечно не претендую на элегантность, но считаю что append'ами тут будет сложнее,нужно будет сравнивать текущую позицию определать что добавлять а что убавить, попробуйте так: http://jsfiddle.net/L3QGe/